# Snappy doesn't recognize the version of a sideload .snap in 15.10

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-core

I've tried to build the webcam-webui example with snapcraft, but when sideloading snappy showed a strange Version string. Everything else seems to work, the program is running.
I also get the same problem with other packages created with snappy build.
This used to work in Snappy 15.4

snappy output:

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$ snappy list -v
Name          Date       Version      Developer  
ubuntu-core   2015-11-13 10           ubuntu*    
webcam-webui  2015-11-22 IGISgOTUdAHf sideload*  
webdm         2015-11-13 0.9.4        canonical* 
generic-amd64 2015-11-13 1.4          canonical*
```

package.yaml content in /apps/webcam-webui.sideload/IGISgOTUdAHf/meta/

```
architectures:
- amd64
icon: meta/icon.png
name: webcam-webui
services:
- name: webcam-webui
  start: bin/webcam-webui.wrapper
vendor: Vendor <email@example.com>
version: 1
package.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, currently Snappy shows a hash instead of the version for sideloaded apps. You'll notice you can actually install the same version of a snap multiple times if you're sideloading it, as the hash changes. You only get a valid version if you install from the store.

This isn't a bug, but it's a bit unintuitive, and it will be changing soon as we move to separating the dev's version from the store version.

Comment: That explains a lot. THX! Which changes are to be expected when the dev's version will be separated from the store version? Will this impact eg the location of the app or the writable directory?